# how to make a stacked bar plot with one bar for many variables

Tags: r

my data "chir" has some variables look like this:

- N1_re N2_re N3_re
- yes no no
- no yes no
- na ye yes
- no na no

all the variables contain like 100 values like yes, no and na, now I need a stacked bar plot with only one bar to show how many yes, no and na the variables have together, without to differentiate them.
I tried to put them together first like this:

```
vars=c("N1_re", "N2_re", "N3_re")
```

and then

```
barplot(matrix(c(table(chir$vars), ncol=1)))
```

which didn't work, and then I tried to melt these to variables first like this:

```
melt1=melt(chir, measure.vars=c("N1_re", "N2_re", "N3_re"), var="zpd")
```

but it says " arguments imply differing number of rows: 98, 196"

maybe there is another way to make the plot without to melt?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Using your data for chir (correcting for typos):

```
data <- rbind(chir,chir,chir,chir)      # just to have a bigger dataset

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

ggdata = melt(chir,measure.vars=1:3)
ggplot(ggdata, aes(x=variable)) + stat_bin(aes(fill=value))
```

gives:
[image]

```
ggplot(ggdata, aes(x=1)) + stat_bin(aes(fill=value))
```

gives:
[image]

Is this what you want??

Comment: thanks! it looks good, but I tried this and it says "arguments imply differing number of rows: 98, 196", is it because I used read.spss to read the data?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really familiar with the SPSS file format. This error implies that not all columns have the same number of rows, which can happen if the read function is misinterpreting a separator character. For instance in `read.table(...)`, the default separator is space, but in some datasets a missing value is represented by space, so `read.table(...)` shifts everything after the missing value over by one column. I've had this problem myself and it can result in the error above. Can you save the SPSS data to csv or tab delimited text?